# forking Pug vs Pug plugins

Tags: pug, nlg

I'm writing a natural language generator (NLG) system based on pug - it's called [FreeNLG](https://github.com/ludans/freenlg).

I had to add new syntaxic elements to Pug, for instance to declare synonyms:

```
span
  synz
    syn
      | some text
    syn
      | another text
```

(which generates randomly 'some text' or 'another text').

I have forked Pug to be able to customize the lexer parser walker and code-gen. It works all fine.

But

I wonder if I could have done the same thing (adding new syntaxic elements) without forking, just with plugins - because I don't really like the idea of having to maintain my own fork of some parts of Pug.

Is it possible to add new syntaxic elements to Pug only via plugins, without a fork ?

Comment: You could use mixins to declare new elements

Comment: Sure, that's what I did at the beginning. But I want to add new structures (like if/then switch/case etc.) the mixin approach doesn't work.

Comment: [This project on GitHub](https://github.com/hildjj/xmlpug) uses a fork of pug, perhaps it'll be useful to give it a look?